# Increment a cell by X repeatedly until it reaches Y, then decrement by X once

Tags: google-sheets

In Google sheets, I need to add X number of days to a passed date repeatedly until before it surpasses today's date.

[In my example sheet,](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9vBShVK_iyxOelo1Dc0THVRJtP3U0pmiPcxbrLLSJ0/edit?usp=sharing) assume today's date is always 7/29/2023. If I am incrementing 7/18/2023 by 3 days repeatedly before reaching today's date of 7/29/2023, then the date would stop at 7/27/2023. If I add 3 more to 7/27/2023, then that would surpass today's date and be 7/30/2023 which shouldn't happen. The output needs to stop at the final incriment before surpassing or equaling today's date.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Please write your formula in the form of an array formula that calculates down the column.

Comment: Why don't you just set it to yesterday without adding or subtracting anything?

Comment: Because I want to emulate a payment schedule where I know when a recent installment was paid in contrast to the very first payment, it's frequency, and up to today's date. I want to know when the date of the most recent payment was. Just setting it to yesterday doesn't give me the data I need for my context.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Updated formula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9vBShVK_iyxOelo1Dc0THVRJtP3U0pmiPcxbrLLSJ0/edit#gid=597511293)*

```js
map(B4:B,C4:C,lambda(b,c,if(or(c="",b=""),,let(Σ,sequence(days(B1,c)+1,1,c,b),xlookup(B1-1,Σ,Σ,,-1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: I think your first output captures my problem more clearly than your second output. However, I think cell H8 should be July 20th instead of July 29th. In my original problem I state: "The output needs to stop at the final increment before surpassing or equaling today's date." In this case, July 20th (cell C8) plus the 9 days (cell B8) equals today's date (July 29th). Since it equals today's date, then the output in H8 should be July 20th.

Comment: Try the updated formula...